Angular 18 @for returning ERROR TypeError: newCollection[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
I decided to start working in the latest Angular version (Angular 18.1) so far I was working with versions 7 to 14...
I just tried making a lil dummy app to showcase a list of movies...
I made a really basic service that gets some data from an API and show this data in a list in html...
I have decided to use the new @for syntax from the latest angular version but now I am getting this error: ERROR TypeError: newCollection[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
Is this related to new version of nagular or am beeing blind and have overlooked an issue in my code?
EDIT: Console.log works.
Here is the component.ts code:
export class MovielistComponent implements OnInit{
  movies: movie[] = [];
  constructor(
    private movieService: GetMoviesService,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMoviesList();
  }

  getMoviesList() {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.movies = data;
        console.log('Movies: ', this.movies);
      }
    )
  }

}

Here is the html file code:
<ul>
  @for (movie of movies; track movie.attributes) {
    <li>{{ movie.attributes.name }}</li>
  } @empty {
    <li>There are no items.</li>
  }
</ul>

And here is the model.ts code:
export interface movie {
  id: number,
  attributes: {
    name: string,
    imageUrl: string,
    synopsis: string,
    year: string,
    genre: string,
  }
}

As requested here is the API response:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "The Shawshank Redemption",
                "imageUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDE3ODcxYzMtY2YzZC00NmNlLWJiNDMtZDViZWM2MzIxZDYwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjAwNDUxODI@._V1_FMjpg_UY1800_.jpg",
                "synopsis": "Over the course of several years, two convicts form a friendship, seeking consolation and, eventually, redemption through basic compassion.",
                "year": "1994",
                "genre": "drama",
                "createdAt": "2024-07-16T12:34:06.769Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-07-16T12:36:29.952Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-07-16T12:36:29.951Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "The Godfather",
                "imageUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_FMjpg_UY1982_.jpg",
                "synopsis": "Don Vito Corleone, head of a mafia family, decides to hand over his empire to his youngest son, Michael. However, his decision unintentionally puts the lives of his loved ones in grave danger.",
                "year": "1972",
                "genre": "crime, drama",
                "createdAt": "2024-07-16T12:36:14.143Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-07-16T12:36:15.723Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-07-16T12:36:15.720Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "The Dark Knight",
                "imageUrl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_FMjpg_UY2048_.jpg",
                "synopsis": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, Batman must accept one of the greatest psychological and physical tests of his ability to fight injustice.",
                "year": "2008",
                "genre": "action, crime, drama, thriller",
                "createdAt": "2024-07-22T09:37:42.564Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-07-22T09:38:19.346Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-07-22T09:38:19.343Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 3
        }
    }
}


please share the API response

Use track movie.id, the "track" is for an unique "key".NOTE1: it's looks like in "this.movies" you have not an array. NOTE2: generally it's use PascalCase to define an interface or a class, better "interface Movie" than interface movie"

@NarenMurali I have updated the question with API response

You can also add interfaces for the response coming from the API.
export interface Pagination{
    page: number;
    pageSize: number;
    pageCount: number;
    total: number;
}

export interface GetMoviesResponse {
    data: movie[];
    meta: Pagination;
}

You have to access the data property inside the response, which is the array.
Generally we get this error when we try to use an object on an ngFor or @for ERROR TypeError: newCollection[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
export class MovielistComponent implements OnInit{
  movies: movie[] = [];
  constructor(
    private movieService: GetMoviesService,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMoviesList();
  }

  getMoviesList() {
    this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(
      (data: GetMoviesResponse) => {
        this.movies = data.data; // changed here!
        console.log('Movies: ', this.movies);
      }
    )
  }

}


Now I am getting this: [ERROR] TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'. [plugin angular-compiler]
src/app/movielist/movielist.component.ts:27:27:
  27 │         this.movies = data['data']; // changed here!
     ╵                            ~~~~~~


@weinde try my updated answer, with interfaces for the response.

In what file do I put the first part of your code (the interfaces)?

@weinde separate files will be better so that the code is organized, each interface a separate file, with <<interfacename>>.model.ts

Yes I did that but now I am getting TS2304: Cannot find name 'GetMoviesResponse'.
src/app/movielist/movielist.component.ts:26:13:
26 │       (data: GetMoviesResponse) => {
╵

@weinde You need to import it, from the file, try hovering over the error and import it on quick fixes\

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You need to access the data property. You rename the argument of the subscribe to response to understand the difference.
Also not you can use the inject instead of constructor to inject the service. Also you should unsubscribe the subscriber`
export class MovielistComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: movie[] = [];
  private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
  private movieService = inject(GetMoviesService)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMoviesList();
  }

  getMoviesList() {
    this.movieService.getMovies().pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe(
      (response:{[key:string]:value}) => {
        this.movies:  = response['data'] || [];
        console.log('Movies: ', this.movies);
      }
    )
  }

}

<ul>
  @for (movie of movies; track movie.id) {
  <li>{{ movie.attributes.name }}</li>
  } @empty {
  <li>There are no items.</li>
  }
</ul>

